# How to cross-compile u-boot on cygwin?

Tags: cross-compiling, u-boot

1. install Cygwin & ARM toolchain.
2. add the toolchain into PATH
3. build u-boot

```
$ make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- rpi_0_w_defconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:97: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:458: scripts_basic] Error 2
```

How to let the arm GCC compiler can be recognized?

Update:

The c compiler problem was because I used MinGW. Install GCC via Cygwin setup solved it. Now got another problem after `make`.

```
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
In file included from include/config.h:5,
                 from ./include/common.h:22:
include/configs/rpi.h:10:10: fatal error: asm/arch/timer.h: No such file or dire
ctory
   10 | #include <asm/arch/timer.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.autoconf:77: u-boot.cfg] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- rpi_0_w_defconfig
```

is not cross compiling at all. Host code is compiled to create the .config file based on rpi_0_w_defconfig. So it is the x86 compiler that is not found. Did you install GCC for x86?

Comment: Hi, the cc problem indeed was caused by the wrong host GCC. Now I got another missing header problem, could you please take a look.